# Controller layer test in SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, mocking, spring-test-mvc

I have a controller in my SpringBoot app:

```
@Controller  
@RequestMapping("/v1/item")  
public class Controller{

@Autowired
private ServiceForController service;

@PostMapping()
public String createItem(@ModelAttribute Item item) {
        Item i = service.createItem(item.getName(), item.getDomain());
        return "item-result";
    }
}
```

And I'd like to test it separately from service with a help of mocks.How to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two approaches to do it:

1. To start up the whole SpringBoot context and make a sort of integration tests
   Example:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @SpringBootTest
   @AutoConfigureMockMvc
   public class ControllerTest {
      @Autowired
      private MockMvc mvc;

      @Test
      @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
      public void createItem() throws Exception {
         mvc.perform(post("/v1/item/")
               .param("name", "item")
               .param("domain", "dummy.url.com"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk());
         //check result logic
   }
   ```
2. Test exclusive controller layer and limit the whole loaded context exclusively to it. Example:

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
   @WebMvcTest(controllers = Controller.class)
   public class ControllerTest{
      @Autowired
      private MockMvc mvc;

      @MockBean
      private ServiceForController service;
      //testing methods and their logic
   ...
   }
   ```

Even though the second approach seems more sensible (as for me) in terms of resources used, it may cause plenty of inconveniences due to the lack of beans initialized. For instance, before I decided to try another option, I faced the need to create mocks of at least 5 beans that are added to the context on SpringBoot start in my ContollerTest class.

Thus, I had to switch to the approach with a use of  @SpringBootTest in combination with @SpyBean, that allowed me to call a Mockito verify() method.